# Can I replicate Informix 11.5 tables to SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, database, ssis, informix, database-replication

I am trying to find a way to, as close to real time as possible, have Informix 11.50.FC9GE database data available for SQL Server 2014 SSRS reports.

Right now, we have SSIS (Integration Packages) that are on a 4 hour schedule to go out to our 8 Informix databases via ODBC, gather all of their table data, and update tables on the SQL Server side.

So, table 'abc' exists on all 8 databases. All of that data is input into a single table on the SQL Server. As that data is gathered, an artificial column is created to say which database the data came from.

```
    Select *, "250" as db from abc
```

This process takes about 1-2 hours to complete. If someone attempts to run a report during this time, they get skewed data.

My hope is to have all of the table data in the SQL Server, and only pass over changed data.

I was looking at SQL Server Replication, but it doesn't look like it can replicate from a Non-SQL Server database?

I also started looking at IBM InfoSphere Change Data Capture 6.5. I installed the Access Server and Management Console on a Windows server with one of my Informix databases.

I installed InfoSphere CDC Configuration Tool (Instance) on the SQL Server with the Database entries pointing to the Informix server, but when I try to start that Instance I get the error:

**IBM InfoSphere Change Data Capture could not identify a supported default database encoding. The detected encoding is null. Please override the encoding with a supported IANA encoding name that matches or is very close to your default database encoding and restart IBM InfoSphere Change Data Capture. Use dmset command line utility to override the encoding.**

I found this command to enter:

dmset -I instanceName database_default_character_encoding=UTF-8

But that gives an error:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\InfoSphere Change Data Capture\Replication Engine for
IBM Informix Dynamic Server\bin>dmset -I vsqldev2014 database_default_character
_encoding=UTF-8
```

> **There is a problem with the IBM InfoSphere Change Data Capture service.**

Frankly, I probably didn't set it up right, because there's hardly any instructions out there. :(

I did find a 3rd party software that appears to work, but they are quoting tens of thousands of dollars. No way, my company would go for that.

Any help/suggestions?

Comment: Maybe a silly suggestion but, what if you just create the IDS server in SQLServer as linked servers (ODBC/OLEDB) and query the table as if they was a SQLServer one?

Comment: Not a silly suggestion at all. Unfortunately, SQL Server doesn't connect to Informix. :(

Comment: Umm, you can use SQLServer linked server to connect to any relational database, just install the ODBC driver or the OLEDB provider and create a link. After that you would be able to query the "non-SQLServer" database withtin SQLServer.  
Check these links:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/linked-servers-database-engine